# Where is this 2nd /head tag coming from, and how to I remove it?

Tags: html, wordpress

I have been having problems with my site and I just realized I have 2  tags. This is a wordpress theme, and I'm not sure where this extra  tag is, and what I need to do remove it. Any ideas?

On a side note, there's no telling how long that extra tag has been there, what sort of problems would this have had for my site?

Thanks.

```
<head>  
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
        <link rel="pingback" href="http://noahsdad.com/xmlrpc.php" />
        <title>Noah&#039;s Dad - A Blog About Noah, Down Syndrome, His Family and the Videos, Pictures and Facts that Tell Their Story</title>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                var _gaq = _gaq || [];
                _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-7239203-2']);
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

                (function() {
                    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                })();
            </script>
                </head>
                <body class="home blog custom-background">


<script type='text/javascript'> 
(function(){ 
var bsa = document.createElement('script'); 
bsa.type = 'text/javascript'; 
bsa.async = true; 
bsa.src = '//cdn.beaconads.com/ac/beaconads.js'; 
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(bsa); 
})(); 
</script> 


<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast WordPress SEO plugin v1.1.5 - http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/ -->
<meta name="description" content="We invite you to join the story we are telling through our daily one minute videos about our son who was born with Down syndrome. We will share facts, information, therapy resources, and lots more."/>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://noahsdad.com/" />
<link rel="next" href="http://noahsdad.com/page/2/" />
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="bM3Xh77FD51oIfTMMStTA5VF0dLwInO00n_Z787BXdo" />
<meta name="msvalidate.01" content="FE5E9CAC2BE0360684519396A5E187CF" />
<meta property='og:locale' content='en_US'/>
<meta property='fb:page_id' content='164848533579702'/>
<meta property='og:title' content='Noah&#039;s Dad'/>
<meta property='og:description' content='We invite you to join the story we are telling through our daily one minute videos about our son who was born with Down syndrome. We will share facts, information, therapy resources, and lots more.'/>
<meta property='og:url' content='http://noahsdad.com/'/>
<meta property='og:site_name' content='Noah&#039;s Dad'/>
<meta property='og:type' content='website'/>
<!-- / Yoast WordPress SEO plugin. -->

<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Noah&#039;s Dad &raquo; Feed" href="http://noahsdad.com/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Noah&#039;s Dad &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://noahsdad.com/comments/feed/" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wpinstagram-css'  href='http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/plugins/instagram-for-wordpress/wpinstagram.css?ver=0.3.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='fancybox-css-css'  href='http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/plugins/instagram-for-wordpress/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='tentblogger-gravatar-reminder-css'  href='http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/plugins/tentblogger-gravatar-reminder/css/style.css?ver=3.3.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='tentblogger-rss-reminder-css'  href='http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/plugins/tentblogger-rss-reminder/css/style.css?ver=3.3.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='nrelate-style-common-0-05-1-css'  href='http://static.nrelate.com/common_wp/0.05.1/nrelate-panels-common.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='nrelate-ie6-0-05-1-css'  href='http://static.nrelate.com/common_wp/0.05.1/ie6-panels.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<![endif]-->
<link rel='stylesheet' id='nrelate-style-default-0-05-1-css'  href='http://static.nrelate.com/common_wp/0.05.1/nrelate-text-default.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/themes/standard3/css/lib/bootstrap.css?ver=3.3.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-responsive-css'  href='http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/themes/standard3/css/lib/bootstrap-responsive.css?ver=3.3.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='standard-css'  href='http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/themes/eightbit-standard-child-theme-kit-23729a7/style.css?ver=3.3.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='sharedaddy-css'  href='http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/sharedaddy/sharing.css?ver=3.3.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script>
        __kws = 11124;
        (function() {
            var kws = document.createElement('script'); kws.async = true;
            kws.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://d2qi79k7w4ifvj.cloudfront.net' : 'http://dl.keywordstrategy.org') + '/track.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(kws, s);
        })();
    </script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://noahsdad.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/plugins/instagram-for-wordpress/js/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/plugins/instagram-for-wordpress/js/jquery.cycle.lite-1.5.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/plugins/instagram-for-wordpress/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/plugins/instagram-for-wordpress/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/themes/standard3/lib/activity/js/widget.js?ver=3.3.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/plugins/nrelate-most-popular/admin/common_frontend.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/themes/standard3/js/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.js?ver=3.3.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/themes/standard3/js/lib/jquery.fitvids.js?ver=3.3.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/themes/standard3/js/theme.js?ver=3.3.2'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://noahsdad.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://noahsdad.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<link rel='shortlink' href='http://wp.me/1Az7o' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/plugins/digg-digg/include/../css/diggdigg-style.css?ver=5.2.6" type="text/css" media="screen" /><link rel="image_src" href="http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/down-syndrome-children-playing-kids-playing-bounce-house-1-640x395.jpg" /><script>
        __kws = 11124;
        (function() {
            var kws = document.createElement('script'); kws.async = true;
            kws.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://d2qi79k7w4ifvj.cloudfront.net' : 'http://dl.keywordstrategy.org') + '/track.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(kws, s);
        })();
    </script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://noahsdad.api.oneall.com/socialize/library.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-page-numbers/classic/wp-page-numbers.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />          <style type="text/css">
                                    #site-title,
                    #site-description,
                    #logo {
                        position: absolute !important;
                        clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
                        clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
                    }

            </style>
        <style type="text/css">
body.custom-background { background-color: #1A1A1A; }
</style>
<style type="text/css">.broken_link, a.broken_link {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}</style>   </head>
    <body class="home blog custom-background">



                    <div id="header" class="imageyup">
                <div id="head-wrapper" class="clearfix">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
```

Comment: You'd have to open the header template for your theme and look at what things are included that construct the output as you've posted above.  I don't think anyone would be able to answer without seeing that too.

Comment: It looks like some of your plugins might be adding things that are meant for the <head> but aren't in the correct location.  Have you tried disabling them one-by-one to see if that helps?

Comment: @Sparky672 thanks. That's where it was. Forget to delete a few lines of code. Thanks. :)

Comment: @ryan can you tell what plug ins are doing that?

Comment: I can't because I don't know what plugins you have installed, but you could deactivate your plugins one-by-one, look at the source, and see when the offending code disappears.

Comment: @ryan I think I've fixed the problem. Can you look at the source code and see if it looks like it's stil doing it.

Comment: I took a look at the header for noahsdad.com and it looks like you fixed it. Was it an offending plugin?

Comment: It looks like it was a typo in the html. :( Now I've just gotta figure out why it's getting soooooo many valdation errors. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to open the header template for your theme and look at what things are included that construct the output as you've posted above.