# Best practice to add java script to Wordpress child theme?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to find a way to add some java script to my wordpress child theme and I'm not sure of the best practice to do this.

I've copied the header.php file to my child theme, but let's say for instance I want to add the google ant code. Some suggest adding it up top and others say in the footer. Same goes for the Facebook code and various other code.

I've been told the best practice for this is to use a plug in to put the code in, others say to use the child theme. Then others say to put the header, others say in the footer.

Which ends up leaving me confused. Would someone mind giving me some feedback on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you got your last question answered, Rick.  You could always do something like this with jQuery and an ajax call so that when the page loads it pulls your code from an external file and loads it. You wouldn't have to edit the template in that case, but you would have to add to your javascript file.

Check out http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/

Comment: I thought you were looking for an alternative to the plugin you had.  I would actually go back to the person who wrote the original plugin and ask him/her to fix it so that it inserts code after the `<body>` tag. This is the 'last post' I was referring to (the one that talks about code in the header) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669004/where-is-this-2nd-head-tag-coming-from-and-how-to-i-remove-it

Comment: Thanks for your feedbaack. I think I was unclear in my previous question. I've updated the question to be a bit clearer. Thanks. :)